# How to get elasticsearch index in sorted order from kibana console?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana, elastic-stack

I want to fetch all the indexed logs file from elastic search in descending order of date from kibana.
Right now when I do:

```
GET _cate/indices
```

It gives me indices in random order as given below:

```
yellow open index-7.10.1-front-ui-2021.02.02      AbT9OEM-RP6OYOvY1xE1PQ 1 1  6045      0   2.8mb   2.8mb
yellow open index-7.10.1-front-ui-2021.02.03      TXxJUyXdRiSK6S0RZtc3eQ 1 1  6057      0   2.7mb   2.7mb
yellow open index-7.10.1-front-ui-2021.01.31
```

But I want it in the sorted order of date like given below:

```
yellow open index-7.10.1-front-ui-2021.02.03      TXxJUyXdRiSK6S0RZtc3eQ 1 1  6057      0   2.7mb   2.7mb
yellow open index-7.10.1-front-ui-2021.02.02      AbT9OEM-RP6OYOvY1xE1PQ 1 1  6045      0   2.8mb   2.8mb
yellow open index-7.10.1-front-ui-2021.01.31
```

Please let me know if it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can sort the lines using the [`s` query string parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html#sort) with the column name on which you'd like to sort:

```
GET _cat/indices?v&s=index:desc
```